# Can I link actions between two d3 charts?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

Very casual javscript user here. Hopefully this makes sense.

I am tracking 20 different series on a stacked area chart with nvd3.js. These series fluctuate between positive and negative values, some on a huge base and some on a small base. The result is that - when one of the really big series is below the x axis - it pushes everything else underneath too, and the positive series won't appear above the x axis until you filter out the bigger players using the key.

The technically inelegant but good looking solution I have come up with is to split all of my negative values into one array, and all of my positives into another. The top half of the page is a positive values graph, the bottom half is negative values and they line up pretty nicely.

The weakness with this approach is when you go to interact with it as an end user. If I filter out a series (by unchecking it in the key) or change the graph mode (with the type selector) or zoom in on a series (by clicking it so the graph refocuses to that series only) then it will only affect whichever graph you clicked on. I would like to adjust these three click events (and any others I've missed?) so that your action is synchronised across both graphs.

Is this achievable? Any reading material I can dig through where somebody has done something similar? I imagine linking two representations of one data set (e.g a pie and column graph) is vaguely analogous.